# Django collectstatic not working with django-pipeline and yui-compressor

Tags: django, yui-compressor, broken-pipe

I've installed [django-pipeline](https://github.com/cyberdelia/django-pipeline/) on my Django 1.4.1 application under a virtualenv but when I run `python manage.py collectstatic`, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/home/hg/VIRTUALENVS/movie/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 459, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/hg/VIRTUALENVS/movie/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/hg/VIRTUALENVS/movie/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/hg/VIRTUALENVS/movie/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/hg/VIRTUALENVS/movie/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/home/hg/VIRTUALENVS/movie/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 163, in handle_noargs
    collected = self.collect()
  File "/home/hg/VIRTUALENVS/movie/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 119, in collect
    dry_run=self.dry_run)
  File "/home/hg/VIRTUALENVS/movie/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pipeline/storage.py", line 30, in post_process
    packager.pack_stylesheets(package)
  File "/home/hg/VIRTUALENVS/movie/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pipeline/packager.py", line 90, in pack_stylesheets
    variant=package.variant, **kwargs)
  File "/home/hg/VIRTUALENVS/movie/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pipeline/packager.py", line 100, in pack
    content = compress(paths, **kwargs)
  File "/home/hg/VIRTUALENVS/movie/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pipeline/compressors/__init__.py", line 76, in compress_css
    css = getattr(compressor(verbose=self.verbose), 'compress_css')(css)
  File "/home/hg/VIRTUALENVS/movie/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pipeline/compressors/yui.py", line 14, in compress_css
    return self.compress_common(css, 'css', settings.PIPELINE_YUI_CSS_ARGUMENTS)
  File "/home/hg/VIRTUALENVS/movie/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pipeline/compressors/yui.py", line 8, in compress_common
    return self.execute_command(command, content)
  File "/home/hg/VIRTUALENVS/movie/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pipeline/compressors/__init__.py", line 235, in execute_command
    pipe.stdin.write(smart_str(content))
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

My settings are:

```
# static
STATIC_ROOT = join(REPOSITORY_ROOT, 'static_collected')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (join(REPOSITORY_ROOT, 'static'),)
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)

# pipeline (css/js compression)
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'pipeline.storage.PipelineCachedStorage'
PIPELINE = True
PIPELINE_CSS = {
    'base_style': {
        'source_filenames': (
            'css/style.css',
            'css/effects.css',
            'css/rs_style.css',
            'css/jq/jquery-ui-movieplayer.css',
        ),
        'output_filename': 'CACHE/css/style.css',
    },
}

PIPELINE_JS = {
    'base_scripts': {
        'source_filenames': (
          'js/jq/jquery.js',
          'js/mv.core.js',
          'js/toolbox/toolbox.core.js',
          'js/swfobject.js',
          'swf/jwplayer5.9.2156.js',
          'js/jq/jquery-ui.custom.min.js',
          'js/mongo_autocomplete.js',
          'js/rs_script.js',
        ),
        'output_filename': 'CACHE/js/scripts.js',
    }
}
```

Before adding django-pipeline the management command worked well, it found everything, so it's not an issue related to finding the static files nor to directory permissions.
The Yuicompressor is installed globally and can be found under `/usr/local/bin/yuicompressor` so I didn't modify `PIPELINE_YUI_BINARY` in my settings.

Any clue?
Thank you!

Comment: Is any of these files empty ?

Comment: no, they all contain at least one row of code. The only difference is that some of them are already minified while others not.

Comment: Does ``python manage.py findstatic css/style.css`` returns something ?

Comment: Yes, two files: the source file in `/static/css/style.css` and the actual file which should be compressed in `/static_collected/css/style.css` (`static_collected` is the `STATIC_ROOT`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

This error means that `yuicompressor` has quit before we had time to send data (most of the time because it crashed or because it wasn't found). Check your `yuicompressor` path, and check if `yuicompressor` actually works.

Comment: Ok got it! It was a problem of misunderstanding a bad naming...
`/usr/local/bin/yuicompressor` installed with "pip" is only a python script which calls the Yuicompressor jar file, the package DOES NOT contain the actual java library.
The jar needs to be installed using "apt" and it's called `yui-compressor`...I hate when they use almost the same name for totally different things :( 
Anyway probably now django-pipeline should work but I don't have time to check it as I've already switched to this compressor https://github.com/jezdez/django_compressor/ 
Tnx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Add paths to the executables in the setting, e.g.

```
PIPELINE_YUI_BINARY = '/usr/bin/yui-compressor'
PIPELINE_LESS_BINARY = '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/less/bin/lessc'
```

Paths may differ(especially for lessc, in this example less was installed with "npm install -g less")

Comment: I don't use the Less compiler and the path of yui compressor is the same as in the default settings (as I wrote in my question), so there's no need to redefine it in the settings...